# I'm making a chess board using QML, but having problem in logic building

Tags: qt, qml, chess

I made a GUI of chess board using QML, but don't know how to write logic. And want to add more pieces in the chess board.
And my that specific image piece is limited to only one row(i.e. 0).

I have defined a function called `ruleFun` that gets called when a user clicks on a cell. This function should handle the movement of the chess piece, but I'm having trouble implementing the logic for moving the piece within the rules of chess.  Could you provide guidance or a code example of how to implement the movement logic for the chess piece? I want the piece to move one cell in any direction, considering the specific rules of chess.  Thank you for your help!

```
Window {

    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 400
    title: "Chessboard"

    function ruleFun(row, column)
    {
        imageId.currentPieceRow = row;
        imageId.currentPieceColumn = column;

        imageId.x = row * chessboard.cellWidth + chessboard.cellWidth / 2 - imageId.width / 2;

            imageId.y = column * chessboard.cellHeight + chessboard.cellHeight / 2 - imageId.height / 2;
        }

    GridView
    {
        id: chessboard
        anchors.fill: parent
        cellWidth: chessboard.width / 8
        cellHeight: chessboard.height / 8
        model: 64
        delegate: Rectangle
        {
            width: chessboard.cellWidth
            height: chessboard.cellHeight
            color: (model.data % 2 === 0 && model.row % 2 === 0) || (model.data % 2 !== 0 && model.row % 2 !== 0) ? "white" : "black"
            border.color: "red"

            MouseArea
            {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked:
                {
                    ruleFun(model.row, model.column);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Image
    {
        id: imageId
        source: "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/1f/8a/b6/1f8ab66a7a7b6c5dd740ce588ccee484.jpg"
        width: chessboard.cellWidth
        height: chessboard.cellHeight
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
        property int currentPieceRow: 0
        property int currentPieceColumn: 0
    } }
```

Answer (score -1):

I would try to separate the logic from the view as much as possible. You can do this by adding a new QML file which has a light-weight object as top-level (QtObject or Item). In there you create the needed functions, and properties for game-state.

Regarding the game-state, you would need to distinguish between selecting a piece to move and selecting a cell to move that piece to and which player has the turn. Also the list of pieces would be game-state, for this you can use a ListModel.

So putting this together, I would code the following:

ChessGame.qml

```
//import x/y/z

QtObject {
    property int currentPlayer
    property int selectedPiece

    readonly property ListModel pieces : ListModel {
        ListElement {
            type: "queen"
            icon: "..."
            player: 0
            row: 0
            column: 4
        }
        ListElement {
            type: "queen"
            icon: "..."
            player: 1
            row: 8
            column: 5
        }
        //...
    }
    property var allowed: []

    function select(idx)
    {
        if(pieces.get(selectedPiece).player != currentPlayer)
           return
        selectedPiece = idx
        //calculate cells to which can be moved based on type
    }
    function move(row, column)
    {
        if(selectedPiece < 0)
           return
        if(pieces.get(selectedPiece).player != currentPlayer)
           return
        if(!<allowed move>)
           return

        pieces.get(selectedPiece).row = row
        pieces.get(selectedPiece).column = column
        currentPlayer = 1-currentPlayer
    }
}
```

And your view would be something like this:

```
//import x/y/z
Window {

    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 400
    title: "Chessboard"

    ChessGame {
        id: game
    }


    GridView
    {
        id: chessboard
        anchors.fill: parent
        cellWidth: chessboard.width / 8
        cellHeight: chessboard.height / 8
        model: 64
        delegate: Rectangle {
            id: cellDelegate
            width: chessboard.cellWidth
            height: chessboard.cellHeight
            property int row: floor(modelData / 8)
            property int col: modelData % 8
        
            color: (col % 2 === 0 && row % 2 === 0) || (col % 2 !== 0 && row % 2 !== 0) ? "white" : "black"
            border.color: "red"

            MouseArea
            {
                anchors.fill: parent
                enabled: game.allowed.includes([cellDelegate.row, cellDelegate.col])
                onClicked:
                {
                    game.move(cellDelegate.row, cellDelegate.col)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Repeater {
        model: game.pieces

        delegate: Image {
            source: model.icon
            x: model.row * chessboard.cellHeight
            y: model.column * chessboard.cellWidth

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    game.select(index)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: this is not tested and some parts are missing as homework for the reader

Answer (score -1):

By the way your alternating color pattern is not correct. Here is the updated one.

```
    // Calculate the row and column indices
    property int row: Math.floor(index / 8)
    property int column: index % 8

    Rectangle {
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        
        // Use this logic for alternating black and white cells
        color: (column % 2 === 0 && row % 2 === 0) || (column % 2 !== 0 && row % 2 !== 0) ? "white" : "black"
        border.color: "red"

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
             
            onClicked: {
                ruleFun(row, column);
            }
        }
    }
```

Your image must also have a transparent background. Use a png file not a jpg.